# AppIcon does not show in setting screen(in Apple ID logins page)

Tags: ios, appicon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxS3Q.jpg)The icon can show both on homeScreen an in game.But can not show in appleID logins page. All image has been set well in xcode AppIcon.

Comment: Can you please share screenshot??

Comment: i have been share screenshot in the link. please have a look